# Can I use the Matlab Parallel Computing Toolbox with 64 bit linux (using Matlab R2012b)?

Tags: matlab

Sorry for the noob question.  I'm using Matlab version R2012b on a computer that's running 64 bit Linux.  It seems that no version of Matlab's parallel computing toolbox will work for me.  Can anyone please tell me if I'm wrong, or else confirm that I'm correct?  Thanks.

Comment: What `>>matlabpool` gives you?

Comment: Also, do you have an appropriate licence?

Comment: What errors do you get?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I recall, Matlab runs as 32bit on 64bit Linux up until R2013a. Try 32bit version of computing toolbox?